# When I try to set a variable in a class with setVariable It doesn't set it

Tags: java, android

I am new to java and I am trying to set a variable in a class.
I wrote a function to scrape a data from a website and set it to a variable.

```
private void GetDollarValue(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            final Currencies currency = new Currencies();
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://kur.doviz.com/serbest-piyasa/amerikan-dolari").get();
                    Elements textElements = doc.getElementsByClass("text-xl font-semibold text-white");
                    currency.setDollar(Double.parseDouble(textElements.text()));
                } catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I run the function in onCreate method `GetDollarValue();` to set dollar variable but when I try to process the dollar variable using `getDollar();` it gives me number of 0.0

So I can `setDollar();` outside of the function but when I try to set it in the function it doesn't set it.

Here is the class in case you want to see it:

```
package com.agent.mahser;

public class Currencies {
    private double dollar;

    public double getDollar() {
        return dollar;
    }

    public void setDollar(double dollar) {
        this.dollar = dollar;
    }

    public double getEuro() {
        return euro;
    }

    public void setEuro(double euro) {
        this.euro = euro;
    }

    private double euro;
}
```

Comment: can we see your activity class calling this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen because you're making an async call in your `getDollarValue()` method. Move all the logic of this method out of the `Runnable`. Also, where exactly are you calling the `getDollar()` method? Cause you've created a variable `currency`, which will be visible only inside the `getDollarValue()` method. It should be moved higher at the class level.

Comment: I made the variable `static` and deleted the `Runnable` and now I can set and get the variable but I found out my problem is that I can't pass through `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://kur.doviz.com/serbest-piyasa/amerikan-dolari").get();` that line of code. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: No problem i fixed it.